# How to fix error when using studpermu.test with large dataset

Tags: r, spatstat

I am using studpermu.test on a large hyperframe of ppp objects and it returns an error.

I am using studpermu.test on a large hyperframe of 250 ppp objects, each with thousands of points (~ 2000-5000), and a grouping factor with 5 levels, with equal group sizes of 50. The function runs successfully on a smaller subset of point patterns but returns an error when I try to run the function on the whole hyperframe.

Here is a smaller reproducible example which gives the same error.

```
X <- runifpoint(20, nsim = 250)
h <- hyperframe(ppp = X, group = rep(1:5, each=50))
studpermu.test(h, ppp ~ group)

Error in if (npossible < max(100, nperm)) warning("Don't expect exact results - group sizes are too small") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
In addition: Warning message: In factorial(sum(m)) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the current CRAN version of spatstat. Here is a small reproducible example (which it would have been great if you provided in your question):

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.61-0       (nickname: 'Puppy zoomies') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
X <- runifpoint(20, nsim = 250)
h <- hyperframe(ppp = X, group = rep(1:5, each=50))
studpermu.test(h, ppp ~ group)
#> Error in if (npossible < max(100, nperm)) warning("Don't expect exact results - group sizes are too small"): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is now fixed in the development version of spatstat. For now you can install the development version from GitHub which should fix the issue:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("spatstat/spatstat")
```

With this version I get (didn't set a seed so results may vary, but no error should occur):

```r
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.61-0.021       (nickname: 'New improved formula') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
X <- runifpoint(20, nsim = 250)
h <- hyperframe(ppp = X, group = rep(1:5, each=50))
studpermu.test(h, ppp ~ group)
#> 
#>  Studentized permutation test for grouped point patterns
#>  ppp ~ group
#>  5 groups: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
#>  summary function: Kest, evaluated on r in [0, 0.25]
#>  test statistic: T, 999 random permutations
#> 
#> data:  h
#> T = 3.6133, p-value = 0.125
#> alternative hypothesis: not the same K-function
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I could not install the studpermutest.R branch from GitHub      `> library(remotes)
> install_github("spatstat/spatstat", ref = "studpermutest.R")
Downloading GitHub repo spatstat/spatstat@studpermutest.R
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/spatstat/spatstat/tarball/studpermutest.R'`

Comment: The branch has been merged into master and deleted, so you should just do `install_github("spatstat/spatstat")`. I will update the answer accordingly. If this fixes your problem please consider to accept the answer, so the issue appears as solved in future searches.

Comment: Hi Ege, I think we're getting there, but I am now receiving the error `Error in f[, ind == l] : incorrect number of dimensions` - I have tried using as.solist before hyperframing, removed marks, and tried various settings in the studpermu.test code but to no avail. Unfortunately, I cannot create a reproducible example.

Comment: Without code to reproduce the error, debugging is difficult. What is the result of running `traceback()` after the error occurs?

Comment: I have made a reproducible example which gives the error, 'Error in f[, ind == l] : incorrect number of dimensions'     `W <- runifpoint(1250, nsim = 20)
X <- runifpoint(3000, nsim = 100)
Y <- runifpoint(4500, nsim = 50)
Z <- runifpoint(5000, nsim = 80)
WXYZ <- c(W, X, Y, Z)
h <- hyperframe(ppp = WXYZ, group = rep(1:5, each=50))
h
studpermu.test(h, ppp ~ group)`

Comment: That helped a lot. I think you can fix the problem for now by setting `correction = "border"` in `studpermu.test`. We will think about a better fix in a later version of `spatstat`.

Comment: In spatstat 1.61-0.026 we have applied what we believe to be a general fix for this problem, so you can download the development version from GitHub and use that.

Comment: This is now fixed in the public release of spatstat (version 1.62-0 and later)